# unable to upload image to url location

Tags: java, rest, java-io

I was trying to upload image file to a url location. Although response status code is coming `200`. but image is not getting uploaded. And connection input stream is throwing `Internal Server Error` with `status=500`. Below is my code with output:

```
package pack;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class TESTTEST {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */

    public void go() throws IOException{
        URL url = new URL("https://mobcsao.com/fwct-provider/api/v1/clients/67/images");
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +"d3BpdHM6cGFzc3dvcmQ=");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Fineract-Platform-TenantId", "default");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream outputStream=conn.getOutputStream();

        FileUtils.copyFile(new File("/home/wpitnew/json_example/index.png"), outputStream);
        conn.connect();
        conn.getResponseCode();
        conn.getResponseMessage();
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode()+" :  "+conn.getResponseMessage());

        InputStream inputStream=conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String abc="";
        while ((abc=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(abc);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            new TESTTEST().go();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

output:

```
200 :  OK

<html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1><p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p><div id='created'>Thu Jan 05 17:51:57 IST 2017</div><div>There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).</div><div>${message}</div></body></html>
```

When I see the location no image is found there..where am I wrong..is there any other alternative?

Comment: so basically the server did have an error with processing your request. As a first try I would add trailing '/' to the URL.

Comment: so are you saying to append "/" after `images` in url.